# When can you substitute in a differential equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm working on a differential equation, but I am not allowed to substitute itself back in at a later step, could someone tell me why?

Here's my work. Consider:
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = W(x(t)) + Q(x(t),y(t), t)$$
Where, $W$ does not explicitly depend on time $t$, meaning $\partial W / \partial t = 0$.

Take a total derivative with respect to $t$ on both sides:
$$\frac{d^2 x(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{\partial W(x(t))}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} +  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} $$
$$\frac{d^2 x(t)}{dt^2} =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [W(x(t)) + Q(x(t), y(t), t)] \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$$
Substitute in the original differential equation:
$$ \frac{d^2 x(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{\partial (dx/dt)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$$

Apparently, the last move was not correct, but I'm unsure why. **Why are you not allowed to resubstitute in a differential equation?**